# change content of file to XML using Sed Unix

Tags: xml, unix, sed

I want to change `STATUS:CONFIRMED` to `<STATUS>CONFIRMED</STATUS>` using sed is it possible ? i can already change `BEGIN:VEVENT` to `<VEVENT>` using this command :

```
sed -i 's|BEGIN:VEVENT|<VEVENT>|g' nameoffile.html
```

But i can't find a way to do change `STATUS:CONFIRMED`

Comment: Show some input data. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't this work:

```
sed -i "s|STATUS:CONFIRMED|<STATUS>CONFIRMED</STATUS>|g" nameoffile.html
```

Tested and working:

```
bash-4.3$ cat > example                                                                                                                                                                                                               
begin:vevent                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
status:confirmed                                                                                                                                                                                         
bash-4.3$ sed -i "s|status:confirmed|<status>confirmed</status>|g" example                                                                                                                                                        
bash-4.3$ tail example    
begin:vevent                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<status>confirmed</status>


bash-4.3$ sed --version                                                                                                                                                                                                               
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

I double checked and actually there's no need to escape any character in the previous command.

Probably there is an issue concerning your input datam it could be helpful to give us more information about the input you want to change.

**EDIT**

If you want to generalize the approach to any other "status" type you can use captured groups:

```
sh-4.3$ tail example                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
begin:vevent                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
status:unknown                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
sh-4.3$ sed "s|status:\(\w+\)|<status>\1</status>|g" example                                                                                                                                                                           
begin:vevent                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<status>unknown</status>
```

Comment: Attention, the bad formatting was hiding some XML stuff.

Comment: my post has been edited, what i want is to have <STATUS>CONFIRMED</STATUS>
as a result

Comment: @Sam yes, I modified my answer accordingly!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can we do the same given the fact that we don't know what we will have after "STATUS: " ? ( it can be CONFIRMED, DENIED, INPROGRESS or stuff like that )

Comment: @Sam I answered to your modified question. I suggest you add your comment direclty in your question, so it will be more readable for the other users. And if my answer satisfies your problem consider accepting it ;)